# jquery this.id not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hello people here is my code ...

```
    $ (".input_check").change (function (){

        if ($ (this).is (':checked')) {
            console.log(this.id + 'is checked')
        } else {
            console.log(this.id + 'is not checked')
        }


    });
```

the above code works fine for several check boxes ....But i want to perform check after the page load not after `$ (".input_check").change`.... I tried ...

```
 $ (function () {
if ($ (".input_check").is (':checked')) {
            console.log(this.id + 'is checked')
        }
)}
```

Iam trying to find the ID  `this.id` but not wrking.. I also tried `(this).id` and `this.attr("id")` still not working... :( am getting `undefined` anyways to fix this??

`UPDATE :: I have multiple checkboxes which are checked... I am trying to find multiple ids of those check boxes which are checked`

Comment: while your console.log code demonstrates the test for a checked element, I very much doubt that the required end result is just a bunch of console logs.  It's more likely that you'll want e.g. an array of the IDs of all checked inputs, per my answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`(this).id` and `this.attr("id")` are not proper jQuery syntax for this situation. Should be

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6Wsz/1/)

**Edit based on your comments**

Ok, then what stops you from doing the same on document ready?

```
 $(function() {
     $( ".input_check" ).each(function( index ) {
        if ($ (this).is (':checked')) {
            console.log($(this).attr('id')  + 'is checked')
        } else {
            console.log($(this).attr('id')  + 'is not checked')
        }
     });
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6Wsz/3/)**

Comment: NAA. Better be a comment.

Comment: @ Hanky 웃 Panky what if there are multiple checkboxes checked??

Comment: It will work for all. It will report the id of the box which triggered this event handler

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question. `this.id` (though not jQ), works perfectly and is generally preferable. `this` returns a DOM object and `id` would be the native property, why convert it to a jQ object and then get its attribute when you can get the native property directly.

Comment: I do respect your effort. But, please see this updated fiddle of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/N6Wsz/2/ . This works too.

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky in your fiddle you have done it in the same way as mine,,, by `change event` thats working fine for me also.. iam not asking that.. I want to check when the page loads...without using any `events`

Comment: Ok then see the update @Friend. Sorry abhitalks for not understanding your view earlier. I'll remove the comments

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky Awesome.. I was trying the same :).. but credit goes to you :)

Comment: +1 @Hanky웃Panky: after the edit it is a good answer indeed. :)

Comment: Thanx, I got exactly what i want.

Answer (score 3):

To get the ID of all `:checked` elements as an array:

```
var checked = $('.input_check:checked').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

and check if you have a ID attribute defined in the checkbox