# How to check if two buttons are clicked using jQuery before perform an action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There are two radio buttons called `id="radio1"` and `id="radio2"` and one submit button with  `id="submitbtnr"`. Once the radio button with `id="radio2"` is clicked a list of data is displayed. Then user can read them and can hit submit button. It works fine now.   Here what i want is to send the current session id and document id to the DB table, once user click `id="radio2"` button and then click submit button.

I write my code to send this data to the table once the  `id="radio2"` button is clicked. It also works fine Here is my code at DocumentView.php file

```
jQuery(':radio').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'radio2' ) {
            // if ($('#submitbtnr').change(function(){

            // })) {
            //     alert('Button 1 was clicked');
            // }

            // alert('Button 1 was clicked');


            var user_id = '<?=$_SESSION['user_id'] ?>';//session id
            var doc_id = '<?= $this->doc->id?>'; //current ocd id

             $.ajax({


                type: "POST",
                url:site_url + "?p=doc_cont&a=randomClick", //call randomClick function 
                  data:{user_id:user_id, doc_id:doc_id},  // pass data userid and doc id , here it is randomClick function
                success:function(data){  //get the response back
                }
       });

    }
});
```

But I want to send this data once the  `id="radio2"` button is clicked and then when user click final submit button. How can I apply these two conditions to this code. Can someone help me to solve this I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Shouldn't `this.id` be `$(this).id`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301203/jquery-this-id-not-working

Comment: @UmairKhan, My current code finely worked. This also correct. I took this line from Stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```js
$('[id^=div]').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  Click me
</div>
<div id="div2">
  Click me too
</div>
<div id="div3">
  Click me three
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try, By the way what is this symbol id^=div